# Rsyslog writing to old file after logrotate

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

My rsyslog logrotate config file is -

```
/home/user/logs/*.l {

   daily
   postrotate
     reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
   endscript


}
```

The file is rotating properly but the logs are going into the old log file. The issue gets resolved when I manually restart rsyslog.

I'm running this on CentOS.

Comment: The answer to this question interests me greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was resolved with compress daily instead of rotate. For some reason, it wasn't working on CentOS6.4

Answer (score 4):

`reload syslog` didn't work for me, either. I used `service rsyslog restart` instead.

Comment: Worked for me on CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

restart service is not recommended for it could lose log.
I resolve this problem with:
 1. killall -HUP rsyslogd
 2. kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid)

the pid filename may be syslogd.pid.
HUP lets rsyslogd perform close all open files according to man page.